# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the error(Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index) in GridView_RowUpdating Event. i tried some ideas posted here, but still getting this error.

Code Behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Label stu_name= ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("student_Name"));
}
```

Comment: Try debugging. Possibly it is `-1`, when no row is selected.

Comment: it showing the rowindex(e.RowIndex) correctly

Comment: Add Watch during debugging on 'GridView1.Rows.Count' and 'e.RowIndex' and share the results of both expressions for the investigation of problem.

Comment: ohhh.. it showing the GridView1.Rows.Count as 0 and e.RowIndex as 1(selected row index)

Comment: Do you have ViewState enabled for the GridView1 Control? If not ASP.NET will not be able to work properly for the update on the GridView.

Comment: GridView1.Rows.Count will be 0 always if the ViewState is disabled.

Comment: Yes i set the property to true.but same error occurs. now also it showing the count as 0

Comment: One issue maybe your RowUpdating event get called before DataLoad, Check for RowUpdating event initalization.

Comment: When do you do DataBind?
I guess its in Page_Load. Are you checking for IsPostBack (Databind only when !IsPostBack)?

Comment: No.Actually im binding this grid in another grid_RowCommand Event

Answer (score 0):

While a coder's bias is to get the code to produce the desired result, if an exception has occurred it means it can occur again.

Great to figure out all the data binding and viewstate dark magic, but probably also a good idea to be a bit more conservative in assumptions from the start:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as Grid;
    if (grid == null) return;

    var rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    var rows = grid.Rows;
    if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex > rows.Count - 1) return;
    Label stu_name= ((Label) rows[rowIndex].FindControl("student_Name"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if ViewState is enabled for GridView1.

If ViewState is disabled, ASP.NET will not be able to properly update because for ASP.NET to handle the Update or any other events it needs to preserve the previous data as well.

In case, ViewState==false, `GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]`, will fail because GridView1.Rows.Count will be 0.

Also if you are doing DataBind in Page_Load, then make sure you DataBind only if !IsPostBack.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
 // DataBind Grid ..
```

Comment: just Now I noted,The Rowediting Event Firing Twice,First time it shows the grid.but at the second time showing the EmptyDataTemplate Text

Comment: Ok. Make sure you do not BindData on each PostBack. Check for !IsPostBack before DataBind.